# rowCount returns 0 even if it should not

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$this->db->beginTransaction();
$this->db->query ('LOCK TABLES users WRITE');
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (uname) VALUES (:uname)';
$sth = $this->db->prepare ($sql);
$sth->bindParam (':uname', $uname);
$sth->execute ();
if ($sth->rowCount()==0) {
  $this->db->rollBack();
  $this->db->query ('UNLOCK TABLES');
  throw new Exception('<strong>Oh snap!</strong> User name is taken! Try again.');
}
```

I set up a user in my database manually that is called "test". And when I created a user called "test2" it worked. But whenever I try to create a third user I get `rowCount = 0`.

The `uname` in the db is `varchar(15)`.

```
if(isset($_POST['regUser']) && isset($_POST['regPwd']) && isset($_POST['regConfirmPwd'])) {  
    if($_POST['regPwd'] == $_POST['regConfirmPwd'] ) {  
        $user->newUser($_POST['regUser'], $_POST['regPwd']);

} else {  
    $user->error = "<strong>Oh snap!</strong> The passwords don't match!";
  }  
}
```

Send the post info to my newuser function and it stops on the first bit of code there. Any ideas?

Comment: +1 for information and PDO.

Comment: What is your database structure?

Comment: Are you looking at your actual request? `echo` your full request before you try it in a query on the database.

Comment: How do I echo the full request? I did a debugDumpParams and got `SQL: [41] INSERT INTO users (uname) VALUES (:uname) Params: 1 Key: Name: [6] :uname paramno=-1 name=[6] ":uname" is_param=1 param_type=2 ` in return

Comment: Totally missed the database structure comment. `uid int(PK), uname varchar(15), pwd varchar(300), fname, lname, adress etc`. Had the uname as unique index but removed it for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inserting the user and then rolling back if taken, it might be better to test if that user is available (after locking the table), and then doing the insert with confidence.

Comment: I'm not sure why he is doing a rollback at all. Clearly, if `rowCount == 0`, that means that the `INSERT` failed, which also means that he must be keying on the username (making it unique). Therefore, if the `INSERT` failed, why `rollBack()` at all? Also, I'm not sure that table locking is beneficial in this situation, nor making a transaction. Using a transaction for a single `INSERT` doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: rollbacking to get in the habit of doing it for later ventures, it does nothing in this case, yes. Locking the tables to be safe.

Comment: You don't need to lock the table here because your `INSERT` is designed to fail if another username exists in the table. If another thread performs an `INSERT` with the same username 1 nanosecond before this thread, then you still want this query to fail (and it will). You shouldn't `LOCK` the table unless you it is necessity.